# Eclipse Indigo code analysis fails with boost

Tags: eclipse, boost, code-analysis, eclipse-indigo

Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 fails to parse `<boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp>` header of Boost library and thus reports `boost::is_base_of` as undefined. In particular this disables macro expansion that uses this class.

Here is code sample that demonstrates this problem ([source code](http://pastebin.com/FF0x4Qfs)):

[image]

Eclipse complains on line `DECLARE_TYPE(Foo, Bar)` with error `Symbol 'is_base_of' could not be resolved`. Boost include path is added to the project include paths and Eclipse does not complain about it. Eclipse doesn't complain on any line in `boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp`.

How to make Eclipse expand the macro?

Comment: Related bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373208 this is a bug, but latest nightly build and Juno milestone have it fixed. The problem is that current release of Eclipse doesn't support conditional includes which are used in `boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp`.

Thus when using the latest build or Juno milestone -- macro is correctly expanded.